# how to put line break in excel sheet cell

Tags: php, drupal, export-to-excel

I've so many rows in database table and i want it to be exported in excel sheet. 
My each row represent an individual sale, this sale may contain one or more product and if there is more than one product i'm showing it like this

[image]

above image represent my single row that contain more than one product for a sale.

when i convert the whole recode into excel both product code no are shown as a joined string, But i want to put the line break in excel sheet cell. how can i put the line break in excel sheet programmaticaly.

Comment: I know how to put line break in excel sheet directly by using alt+enter.

Comment: maybe this codes can help: http://brebru.com/asciicodes.html ?

Comment: How to convert Alt+Enter in code

Comment: For some reason, I can't post an answer.  But the way I just figured out how to do it was by echoing out a table onto a page with the headers: `$filename ="report_".date("Y-m-d").".xls"; header('Content-type: application/ms-excel'); header('Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename='.$filename);`.  In the table cell, I just enter a `<br/>` tag where I want the line break.  Works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can put line break using \n in excel sheet. if you want to switch to another cell in same row then you can achieve it by ','...

something like this

```
$data  = $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'].",";
$data .= $row['programEnrollments'][0]['startSessionName'].",\n";
```

Comment: I tried with your both solution but i'm getting the same thing in my excel sheet like this H32565135,\nADH1623,\n and H32565135,ADH1623,  And i'm sure that i'm not converting to it in CSV. How can i put line break in excel sheet cell

Comment: may be your content type is not correct .. try this..

    header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=student_info.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

Comment: Why are u telling me to place csv header. that's not my requirement. I've to export the file in .xls format not in .csv

Comment: then you should user type that supports .xls file. my main intension was to make you aware about your possible mistakes..

Comment: same code may use for csv as well. check it. i am not sure..

Answer (score 0):

If you're exporting XML code to generate your Excel file, you would need to use [PageBreaks](http://www.officekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/excel-prog/106927/Excel-XML-Page-Breaks)

Answer (score 0):

Vikas,

Am I right, that you want to know how to use the replace function with Chr(10)?

Something like:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim SpecialChar

SpecialChar = Chr(10)

Cells.Replace What:=SpecialChar, Replacement:=" ", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink